# Create a transaction filter with unit-of-work

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, unit-of-work

I'm totally new to the ASP.NET framework, so my design pattern might be weird. Feel free to give me any advice. I would be appreciated it.
What I'm trying to do is to create a unit-of-work to handle all repositories and using a filter to control transactions.

But now I'm getting a error when creating transaction, any advice would be grateful and here is the code: https://github.com/SYLin117/csharp_side_project

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for
> type 'ApplicationCore.Contracts.Repositories.IStatusRepository' while attempting to activate 'Infrastructure.Repositories.UnitOfWork'.
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor
> serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor
> descriptor)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor
> descriptor)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1
> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection
> services, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()    at
> Program.$(String[] args) in
> /Users/shaoyulin/SoftwareDev/Antra-WEB/HRM/src/Recruiting/Recruiting.API/Program.cs:line
> 118  ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.InvalidOperationException: Error
> while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> ApplicationCore.Contracts.Repositories.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType: Infrastructure.Repositories.UnitOfWork': Unable to
> resolve service for type
> 'ApplicationCore.Contracts.Repositories.IStatusRepository' while
> attempting to activate 'Infrastructure.Repositories.UnitOfWork'.  --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'ApplicationCore.Contracts.Repositories.IStatusRepository' while
> attempting to activate 'Infrastructure.Repositories.UnitOfWork'.    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type
> implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[]
> parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache
> lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain
> callSiteChain)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor
> descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor
> serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor
> descriptor)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor
> descriptor)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1
> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)<---